# Is a four-variable function less than one?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerical-value, maximum, maximize

I have the following function of four variables

```
f=Sqrt[(1 + w - x + 4 y z) - Sqrt[4 (-w + x) + (1 + w - x + 4 y z)^2]]/Sqrt[2]
```

I want to show that $f(w,x,y,z)<1$ under the conditions $x\geq0,w\geq 1, y>0, z>0$; then, I use `NMaximize[]` command to find the maximum value of $f(w,x,y,z)$, that is

```
NMaximize[{f, x >= 0, w >= 1, y > 0, z > 0}, {w, x, y, z}]
```

If the maximization of $f(w,x,y,z)$ under the previous conditions gives a value less than one, I show that $f(w,x,y,z)<1$. However, the result of the previous code is

```
{1., {w -> 1.42498, x -> 0.00149322, y -> 0., z -> 0.0000601358}}
```

Then, *Mathematica* carries out the numerical maximization with $y=0$ even though I'm using the condition $y>0$ in `NMaximize[]`. Then, my questions are:

**(1) There exists some way to force *Mathematica* to carry out the numerical maximization with** $y>0$ **?**

and

**(2) Is there another simpler way to show $f(w,x,y,z)<1$ (subject to $x\geq0,w\geq 1, y>0, z>0$) with *Mathematica***?

Comment: The expression is not always real-valued in that domain. `In[189]:= f /. {w -> 1, x -> 4, y -> 1/100, z -> 100}

Out[189]= I`

Comment: Evaluate `Maximize[{f, x >= 0, w >= 1, y > 0, z > 0}, {w, x, y, z}]` which returns `Maximize::wksol: Warning: there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; a result on the boundary will be returned.` and `{1, {w -> 2, x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 0}}` This indicates that function was increasing as it approached the boundary and as you get arbitrarily close to boundary (`z == 0` in this instance) the result will be arbitrarily close to `1` Look at `inst = FindInstance[{f == 1 - 10^-20, x >= 0, w >= 1, y > 0, z > 0}, {w, x, y, z}, 1]`

Comment: One other way to ask: `Reduce[x>=0&&w>=1&&y>0&&z>0&&Sqrt[(1+w-x+4y z)-Sqrt[4(-w+x)+(1+w-x+4y z)^2]]/Sqrt[2]>=1,{w,x,y,z}]` instantly returns `False`

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
FindInstance[{f >= 1, x >= 0, w >= 1, y > 0, z > 0}, {w, x, y, z}]
```

returns `{}` which, if one trusts Mathematica, proves that $f$ is strictly less than 1.

I don't personally trust Mathematica, for what it's worth.